# Remember Plotting Command

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, command-line

I used a command in another computer to obtain a surface without using any input more than the command. It returns me a surface like this:

[image]

Anyone knows the command or commands that let me graph something like this without any input?

Comment: Do you have the image only, as in a .jpg or .pdf file, or do you have the output inside a notebook but not the input command?

Comment: I only have the image because I don't have mathematica in my computer, I only have it in the campus computer, but I need more images like this and I don't know the input command.

Comment: `Plot3D[]` will work.

Comment: But I didn't include any input inside the `[]`

Comment: Of course.  You must include a function of two variables ($x$ and $y$) to define the specific function you wish plotted.

Comment: But the command I found didn't ask for any input.

Comment: Try `Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -5,5}, {y,-5,5},MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 5]` for a simple shape.  Then adjust the function, as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListPlot3D[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], 
 InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 DataRange -> {{1, 30}, {1, 30}},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> 5]
```

[image]

You can use `Plot3D[]` and other plotting functions as well.